# How to parse (in R) this API call into a .txt table format? (related to "open government" of Israel :) )

Tags: parsing, r

Israel has released it's budget for all to see, and there is an API to extract the data.  However, I don't know how to parse it into a txt/csv format.

Here is an [example link to make a call for data](http://budget.yeda.us/0021?year=2003&depth=1).

Here is the output:

```
[
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 6075053, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "השכלה גבוהה", 
        "gross_amount_used": 5942975, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 5942975, 
        "budget_id": "0021", 
        "net_amount_used": 5936491, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 5861591, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 5861591
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 5364976, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "השתתפות בתקציב המוסדות להשכלה גבוהה", 
        "gross_amount_used": 5337585, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 5337584, 
        "budget_id": "002102", 
        "net_amount_used": 5331101, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 4985915, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 4985915
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 565495, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "השתתפות בפעולות", 
        "gross_amount_used": 462490, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 462490, 
        "budget_id": "002103", 
        "net_amount_used": 462490, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 559293, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 559293
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 0, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "רזרבה להתייקרויות", 
        "gross_amount_used": 0, 
        "gross_amount_revised": null, 
        "budget_id": "002105", 
        "net_amount_used": null, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 171801, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 171801
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 108000, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "פיתוח מוסדות להשכלה    גבוהה", 
        "gross_amount_used": 108000, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 108000, 
        "budget_id": "002106", 
        "net_amount_used": 108000, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 108000, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 108000
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 23634, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "תחום פעולה כללי", 
        "gross_amount_used": 23634, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 23634, 
        "budget_id": "002101", 
        "net_amount_used": 23634, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 23634, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 23634
    }, 
    {
        "parent": [
            {
                "budget_id": "0021", 
                "title": "השכלה גבוהה"
            }, 
            {
                "budget_id": "00", 
                "title": "המדינה"
            }
        ], 
        "net_amount_revised": 12948, 
        "year": 2003, 
        "title": "פעולות עם משרדים       ומוסדות אחרים", 
        "gross_amount_used": 11266, 
        "gross_amount_revised": 11266, 
        "budget_id": "002104", 
        "net_amount_used": 11266, 
        "inflation_factor": 1.15866084989269, 
        "net_amount_allocated": 12948, 
        "gross_amount_allocated": 12948
    }
]
```

What would be the way to parse this into a table format?

Thanks!

Tal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's JSON. `fromJSON` will turn it into a list for you

```
resp <- getURL("http://budget.yeda.us/0021?year=2003&depth=1")
library(rjson)
resp <- fromJSON(resp)
```

That gets you to list form. For a data frame, try:

```
library(plyr)
resp <- llply(resp, function(x) llply(x, function(y) ifelse(is.null(y), "NULL", y)))
budget <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(resp)) {
  budget <- rbind.fill(budget, data.frame(resp[[i]]))
}
```

The nested `llply` take care of some unpleasantness when creating data frames that include null values.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [the rjson package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) You should be able to do:

```
do.call( 'rbind', fromJSON( file="http://budget.yeda.us/0021?year=2003&depth=1" ) )
```

[edit]

Actually.. that has problems with the variable length internal `parent` list, but should get you half way there

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JSON. Try the rjson package, but some looping or tricky listy fiddling may be required.

Lunchtime now, otherwise I'd have a solution pasted in. Give the non-lunching portion of the  hive mind a few minutes....

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a previous answer but also creates columns for the second `budget_id` and `title` fields in `parent`, not just the first and is structured slightly differently operating on the `parent` and the `rest` separately and then putting them back together.

```
library(rjson)
library(plyr)
js <- fromJSON(file = "http://budget.yeda.us/0021?year=2003&depth=1")

toDF <- function(x) do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(x, as.data.frame))
Null2NA <- function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x

parent1 <- lapply(js, "[[", "parent")
rest <- lapply(js, function(x) lapply(x[-1], Null2NA))
cbind(toDF(parent1), toDF(rest))
```